# Какой использовать layout в Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-layout

Я всего лишь начинающий разработчик под Android и мне хотелось бы узнать все достоинства и недостатки тех или иных layouts в Android. И хотелось бы узнать, какой же все-таки лучше использовать для создания GUI.

Comment: Единственно "правильного" контейнера не существует, иначе тогда другие бы не понадобились. Выбирать компоновщик виджетов нужно из конкретных задач, как требуется разместить элементы внутри. В одном случае будет уместен один контейнер, в другом - другой, в третьем их комбинации. Универсального ответа на ваш вопрос нет и лучшего среди них тоже нет.

Answer (score 1):

На эту тему можно статью написать. Вот хорошее объяснение на [startandroid](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/15-urok-6-vidy-layouts-kljuchevye-otlichija-i-svojstva.html). Есть еще два layout которые не описаны там, это `CoordinatorLayout` и `ConstrainLayout`. Первый нужен для того чтобы, контролировать взаимодействие все элементов, которые лежат в нем. А второй похож на `RelativeLayout` но более гибкий. Про них тоже по отдельности много статей.

Comment: я уже написал статью :)

Comment: Делитесь))). Может что новое узнаю

Comment: этой статьей закрыт данный вопрос